# Blank boxes appearing instead of text in R plots in jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am using R magic to plot in a jupyter notebook, following instructions in https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r. However, with

```
%%R -w 800 -h 480 -u px
plot(mtcars)
```

[my plot shows blank boxes wherever text should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh3aZ.png). There are no warnings or errors printed. Moreover, when I print the plot to pdf instead and open the pdf, the plot looks normal:

```
%%R -w 800 -h 480 -u px
pdf("file.pdf",width=6,height=4,paper='special') 
plot(mtcars)
dev.off()
```

What might be going on?

Output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     digest_0.6.12    grid_3.3.2       plyr_1.8.4      
 [5] gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     rlang_0.1.2     
 [9] stringi_1.1.5    reshape2_1.4.2   lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3    
[13] stringr_1.2.0    munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.3.4
```

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I wish I could--this bug appears even with a fresh conda installation `conda create -n my-r-env -c r r-essentials` but only on this particular machine, so I'm thinking it must be something outside of ggplot2, R, and conda, that is specific to this machine, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Did you figure it out in the end?